# What are the lowest and highest energetic (electron shell) emission lines considering ANY molecule or atom (observed & theoretical)?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, interactions, electronic-band-theory, photon-emission

I am making [this public interactive infographic of the electromagnetic spectrum on the web](http://em-spectrum.e-motiv.net). In it I visualize all interactions of EM waves with matter. And I try to display boundaries for every interaction.

Emission lines is one of the interactions. But what are the boundaries left and right in the electromagnetic spectrum for these kind of interactions (being electron jumps)?
On the lowest energy level I'lm thinking, it must be close to zero. Which atom or molecule has their electrons in the highest level below valence band so the electrons can jump the smallest gap? Since the higher up the more close they are to eachother.
And for which is the highest jump, since several things influence the size of the biggest possible jumps (like electron density, etc.)

And to make things worse, which ones are the ones that have actually been observed (in nature or lab)? This is a whole other aspect. And I'm wondering if I should even consider taking into account the ones that almost never occur, like below 1%.

And I decided to give myself a headache since I divided them into category "outer electron" and "inner electron" jumps, and molecular and atomic emission lines.
(So in the best case, taking all together, I would love to have 8 answers if possible. But anything that anyone can give is much appreciated of course.)

These are the questions that hold me from finishing my project. I've been searching for years. (Eh, yeah, it's a long term hobby.)

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The purely-electronic transitions with the highest energy are the K-shell x-rays, produced by vacancies in the electron shell closest to the nucleus. In [this database](https://www.nist.gov/pml/x-ray-transition-energies-database) you can search by energy or wavelength. Searching for energies between 100 keV and 1 MeV gives mostly x-rays from the actinides, pooping out below 150 keV. I think (you’ll want to read the associated paper to confirm) that a “KL” x-ray is a $2\to1$ transition, that a “KN” x-ray is a $4\to1$ transition, and that the “K-edge” includes capture to the K-shell from the continuum.

The highest-energy x-rays in the NIST database are the K-edge x-rays from the highest-$Z$ element in the database, $_{100}\rm Fm$. There are several superheavy elements which were unknown or unconfirmed in 2005, when the database was made. It seems like a safe bet that the highest-energy K-edge x-rays from a currently-known element would come from $_{118}\rm Og$. But there have only been five or six oganesson atoms ever detected, and while they probably came into being with K-shell vacancies, they probably produced KL x-rays rather than K-edge x-rays. (The folks who made oganesson weren’t looking at the x-rays anyway.) An interesting homework problem for you would be to [compute the energies](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/630611/44126) of x-rays for the heaviest elements.

With the lowest energy, you definitely have a judgement call to make. For one thing, you have the example of the hydrogen Rydberg states, which get arbitrarily close to each other as the principle quantum number gets large. (People talk about the Lyman, Balmer, and Paschen series, where the final state is $n=1,2,3$; the series [are named](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series) up to $n=6$, and apparently the $n=7$ series has been observed.)

But also your definition of “electron jumps” arbitrarily excludes some interactions.
For example, a hydrogen atom in its ground state can undergo a magnetic dipole (M1) transition in which the electron’s spin flips relative to the proton’s spin; this very slow transition is associated with the astrophysically-important 21cm radio line.

Comment: Thanks 4 d help. Some questions..///

From valence/infin. to K shell? And for which molecule/atom? Do you know the frequency, eV or wavelength? Thanks.///

Hydrogen series already embedded in my project. Not the seventh though. But I have already encountered lines much lower on the spectrum from other molecules in the NIC DB.  So, I think this part is wrong? Or am I missing something? What would be the freq. in any case?///

I think I might introduce electron spin flipping as another category or as separate interaction. What would u do? Interesting at the least.///

Any links welcome.

Comment: For hydrogen, I mean that you can in principle have a transition between $n=1\,000\,000$ and $n’=1\,000\,001$, with micro-eV energy. I heard an interesting talk about high-$n$ Rydberg states, about which I remember zero details because it was at least fifteen years ago. For molecules, far-infrared and cooler transitions may have more to do with vibrational modes of the molecule than with “electron jumps”; read your database’s description carefully. For x-rays, see e.g. NIST; the branching ratio for valence electrons to fill a K-shell vacancy may be negligible in practice.

Comment: H:(e jump) lines below the valence band, is that possible? Maybe free atoms in space don't have that band? If so, I am certain to apply this 1% occurrence thingy // I have vibration modes in another interaction. I'll edit the question to clarify. // NIST is what I meant, not NIC, sorry. But you can't check on frequency there, only per molecule. I can't go writing down each highest and lowest freq. for each of them; that will take man months. That's why I ask this question. // I was hoping to get some numbers in this question or at least some links or something. This is getting nowhere..

Comment: (a) I don’t know that there’s any difference in principle between a hypothetical hydrogen transition $n=1\,000\,001\to1\,000\,000$  and the well-attested $n=8\to7$.

Comment: (b) I don’t know which database you’re using, but for x-rays (answer updated) and [molecules](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/MolSpec/freqsearch.html) you *can* search by frequency/energy. The lowest entry in the molecules database is at 82 kHz. But that says more about the size of the database than it does about nature; as a rule, bigger systems have more closely-spaced states and therefore smaller transitions. The large-molecule limit is an infinite crystal, where we can usefully talk about e.g. the “conduction band” where adjacent electron energy states collapse to form a continuum.

Comment: I'm with my hands in my hair. Not only did your NIST link crash my browser and did my own NIST searches gave me no information of occurrence (of the emission lines nor of the commonness of molecules in nature), I am starting to think theoretical emission lines and even observed for uncommon molecules just doesn't give any useful information in an educational tool.

P.S. Are the X-rays in your answer theorethical or opbserved?

Comment: On the other hand asking: "What are the boundaries of e emission lines that occur for more than 1% of the time for the 99% most common atoms and molecules?" would be even more difficult to answer, right? (Even if we  would take 5% resp 95%) 
In the worst case, I'm just gonna give it the X-Ray mentioned above as upper limit and no lower limit.  IT's a shame i will have to abandon subcategories "atomic (outer)", "molecular(outer)" and "inner electron jumps" for which I got arbitrary data years ago  but can't verify it anymore.
I am feeling I am giving up. Any suggestions are welcome.
:'( :'(

Comment: It sounds like I’ve helped you all I can with the molecular databases — that’s not really my jam, and my advice is making you frustrated. The fermium K-edge x-rays have both theoretical and experimental values, which agree to six significant figures.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123989/discussion-between-e-motiv-and-rob).